# How can I measure thread specific time in Android?

Tags: java, android, benchmarking, cpu-time

In standard JVM (e.g., version 1.8), we can access the current thread's time like this:

```
ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean().getCurrentThreadCpuTime();
```

What is the equivalent methodology to get current thread's time in Android (i.e., Dalvik VM).

Comment: Define cpu time.  Do you want time since the CPU was started, time elapsed, wall time, something else?  Also what level of precision are you looking for?

Comment: Also there is no promise even under standard java that currentThreadCpuTime is supported.

Comment: I want to profile running time of a method in Android. If I measure the time with `System.nanoTime()` (e.g., t1=System.nanoTime();  methodCall(); timeDiff = System.nanoTime() - t1;), other timing measurements (e.g., context switch time, other threads running times) will be included into the calculated time difference. So, I just want to calculate the execution time for this specific thread. As far as I know,  in standard Java, we can use 'getCurrentThreadCpuTime()'. But, I don't know how to do this in Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I found this solution in Android:

```
SystemClock.currentThreadTimeMillis();
```

The [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#currentThreadTimeMillis()) states that this method

> Returns milliseconds running in the current thread.

Answer (score 2):

## CPU Time methods

### SystemClock.currentThreadTimeMillis:

From the [implementation](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/jni/android_os_SystemClock.cpp;l=50?q=currentThreadTimeMillis&sq=&ss=android%2Fplatform%2Fsuperproject) you can see that it is using `CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID`, and dividing nanos to millis. Similarly there is [currentThreadTimeMicro](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/jni/android_os_SystemClock.cpp;drc=5c091dc9449b583e18656a8850a61f557dfcc945;l=62). 
These two use the [@CriticalNative](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:art/runtime/native/dalvik_system_VMDebug.cc;l=661?q=threadCpuTimeNanos&ss=android%2Fplatform%2Fsuperproject) annotation which is even faster than `@FastNative`. This special optimisation requires that the method does not use objects, just primitives, and is static. Because of that, no `JNIEnv` is used at all. Similarly with `@FastNative`, these annotations are only for platform calls, and are not dynamically linked, instead are specially linked by the framework beforehand.

### android.os.Debug.threadCpuTimeNanos()

> Get an indication of thread CPU usage.  The value returned indicates
>   the amount of time that the current thread has spent executing code or
>   waiting for certain types of I/O.
>   The time is expressed in nanoseconds, and is only meaningful  when
>   compared to the result from an earlier call.  Note that nanosecond
>   resolution does not imply nanosecond accuracy.

By inspecting Android Runtime (ART), this calls [ThreadCpuNanoTime](http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/xref/art/libartbase/base/time_utils.cc#162) method, which uses the `CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID`. Also, it is marked as a [fast Native method](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:art/runtime/native/dalvik_system_VMDebug.cc;l=661?q=threadCpuTimeNanos&ss=android%2Fplatform%2Fsuperproject) and annotated in Java as `@FastNative`. This allows it to be optimized by speeding up the JNI transitions. I guess that this optimization, similarly to `@CriticalNative`, takes advantage of the fact that they do not need to fully construct/destruct a JNI environment, since there are no really dependencies here. It's essentially just a [syscall](https://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime).

Alternatively, one can implement a JNI method that does the same thing, but that won't have the faster JNI handling.

## Wall clock approaches

Both `System.nanoTime()`, and `currentTimeMillis()` are not bound to a thread, and use `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not familiar with any such equivalent in the Java API.

thinking beyond the Java API, however... could you glean any useful information from `top`?

`top -t` will apparently include thread-specific information in the reporting. here's the result from running on one of my devices:

[image]

there appears to be thread and CPU utilization data available there.

getting access to this output would involve some primitive form of input stream handling, e.g.

```
try {
    final String cmd = "top -t"

    final Process ps = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
    ps.waitFor();

    final InputStream instream = ps.getInputStream();

    ...

} catch(Throwable t) { /* handle errors */ }
} finally { /* clean-up */ }
```